# compact set with neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be topological space,let $(A_\alpha)$ be collection of closed set.(add one more condition $\{A_\alpha\}$ are locally finite)

Prove given compact set $C\subset X$ there always exist a neighborhood $N$ ,with $C\subset N$,such that $N$ intersect only finite many $A_\alpha$

Comment: What have you tried? You will get no complete answers (rather than hints) to no-clue questions.

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Then I suppose only hints will be given to you . You have to try them through hints (The one posting an answer should keep this in mind) .

Comment: This seems to be a false statement trivially taking inifnite many $A_\alpha$ inside $C$

Comment: By the way , you yourself can research some ideas on how this question can be solved ? That will help you a lot, and mathematics is a subject which you can solve only by thinking by yourself . If you think it is false, then maybe it is false, but how will you show it? Think about it.

Comment: taking $C= [0,1]$ and $A_{1/n} = [0,1/n]$ which always lies in $C$ but can't only have finite intersection with $C\subset N$ so it's a false statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113033/discussion-between-anonymous-and-yi-li).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this problem. In a $T_1$ space without isolated points this is never true since I can simply take $A_\alpha$ to be all singletons. $T_1$ ensures each $A_\alpha$ is closed. Lack of isolated points ensures every open set has infinitely many points.

Comment: @freakish maybe this is meant to be a *locally finite* family of closed sets. Then the exercise is a standard one to "lift" points to compact sets it seems.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Can  you provide a bit hint how to prove it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locally finite means that for every point $x$ there is an open neighbourhood $U_x$ that intersects finitely many $A_\alpha$. With this you pick $\{U_x\}_{x\in C}$ which is an open cover of $C$, you take finite subcover and then you define $N$ to be the union of the subcover.